# JS: Grading System of a school Any Fix (Error== undefined)

Tags: javascript

A school has the following rules for the grading system:

```
// a. 45 to 50 - D
// b. 50 to 60 - C
// c. 60 to 80 - B
// d.Above 80 - A
```

Ask the user to enter marks, name as well as Roll No and print the corresponding grade

```js
const school_grading_system = () => {
  let student_details = {
    name_of_student: prompt("Enter your name:"),
    roll_number_of_student: Number(prompt("Enter your Roll No: ")),
    marks_of_student: Number(prompt("Enter your marks out of 100: ")),
    percentage_obtained_student: function() {
      return ((this.marks_of_student / 100) * 100)
    }
  }
  if (this.percentage_obtained_student >= 80 && this.percentage_obtained_student < 80) {
    console.log(`${this.percentage_obtained_student}:Good Job! You have scored A Grade`)
  } else if (this.percentage_obtained_student >= 60 && this.percentage_obtained_student < 60) {
    console.log(`${this.percentage_obtained_student}: Good! You have obtained B Grade`)
  } else if (this.percentage_obtained_student >= 50 && this.percentage_obtained_student < 60) {
    console.log(`${this.percentage_obtained_student}: Good! You have obtained C Grade`)
  } else if (this.percentage_obtained_student >= 45 && this.percentage_obtained_student < 50) {
    console.log(`${this.percentage_obtained_student}: Good! You have obtained D Grade`)
  }
}

console.log(school_grading_system())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Rule 1: Kinda keep it simple 
// As total marks are going to be 100 so no need for a percentage method

const school_grading_system = () => {
  let student_details = {
    name_of_student: prompt("Enter your name:"),
    roll_number_of_student: Number(prompt("Enter your Roll No: ")),
    marks_of_student: Number(prompt("Enter your marks out of 100: "))

  }
  if (student_details.marks_of_student >= 45 && student_details.marks_of_student < 50) {
    return "Grade D"
  } else if (student_details.marks_of_student >= 50 && student_details.marks_of_student < 60) {
    return "Grade C"
  } else if (student_details.marks_of_student >= 60 && student_details.marks_of_student < 80) {
    return "Grade B"
  } else if (student_details.marks_of_student >= 80 && student_details.marks_of_student <= 100) {
    return "Grade A"
  }
}
console.log(school_grading_system())


// Note: I have not displayed the name and marks stuff because I hope you are capable enough to do that so I am leaving that upon you
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter way of doing the grading work:

```js
// 45 to 50 - D
// 50 to 60 - C
// 60 to 80 - B
// Above 80 - A
const grades=[[101,"*** impossible - you must have cheated!"],[80,"A"],[60,"B"],[50,"C"],[45,"D"],[0,"E or below"]];

[95,23,57,-5,45,83,110,74,62].forEach(s=>
  console.log(`your score of ${s} gets you the grade ${(grades.find(([g])=>s>=g)??[0,"below ZERO"])[1]}`))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems within your code that lead to the result being wrong, let's break them down:

- The use of `this` keyword in your `school_grading_system` (outside the `student_details` object) is the `window` object and **NOT** `student_details` object so when you try `this.percentage_obtained_student` that is translated to `window.percentage_obtained_student` and as `window` dosen't have an attribute called `percentage_obtained_student` the result of that call would be `undefined` that lead to deliver the wrong results. So instead of `this.percentage_obtained_student` you should use `student_details.percentage_obtained_student` to get the needed piece of data.
- Another issue is the your conditions found on the `if .. else` statements. Let's imagine a student having `80` as his score, when you say `student_details.percentage_obtained_student >= 80 && student_details.percentage_obtained_student < 80` this condition will never be satisfied because it negates itself as that conditon translates to `IF the SCORE is greater than or equal to 80 AND the score is less than 80` but we cannot have a number bigger or equal and lower than itself at the same time (I couldn't describe more accurately).

With that being said, here's a corrected version of your code:

```js
const school_grading_system = () => {
  let student_details = {
    name_of_student: prompt("Enter your name:"),
    roll_number_of_student: Number(prompt("Enter your Roll No: ")),
    marks_of_student: Number(prompt("Enter your marks out of 100: ")),
  }

  /** the conditons are now refined */
  if (student_details.marks_of_student >= 80) {
    console.log(`${student_details.marks_of_student}:Good Job! You have scored A Grade`)
  } else if (student_details.marks_of_student >= 60) {
    console.log(`${student_details.marks_of_student}: Good! You have obtained B Grade`)
  } else if (student_details.marks_of_student >= 50) {
    console.log(`${student_details.marks_of_student}: Good! You have obtained C Grade`)
  } else if (student_details.marks_of_student >= 45) {
    console.log(`${student_details.marks_of_student}: Good! You have obtained D Grade`)
  }
}

school_grading_system();
```

> By the way, you function has some unhandled cases, to mention some, it doesn't take into consideration the case of a score **LESS THAN** `45`. Also, it doesn't handle wrong user inputs like when the user types a number higher than `100`.